# how to write update table set signout=time.now where id=myid in linq

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

I am trying to update the record but not working.  i have declared active as bool and in database it is bit.

```
enter code here
```

```html
string str = DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();   
    var update = db.Logs.Single(u => u.id == id);
     update.logout = str;
     update.active = false;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```cs
string str = DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString(); 

List<Single> results = (from s in in Logs.Single
                        where s.id == id
                        select s).ToList();

foreach (Single s in results)
{
    s.logout = str;
    s.active = false;
}
```

Comment: Worked well. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```
  db.Logs.Where(x => x.id == id).ToList().ForEach(x =>
                    {
                        x.logout = str;
                        x.active = false;
                    });
```